# border color won't change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate background-color,color and border color to change with jquery but for some reason border color is not changing any idea why? here is the portion of jquery code :

```
$('#tabbed a').hover(function() { 
        $(this).animate({ 
          backgroundColor: "#FBFBFB", 
          color:"#FD7A24",
          borderColor:"#000"
        }, "fast") 
      }, function() { 
        $(this).animate({ 
          backgroundColor: "#FFF",
          color:"#65B1D3",
          borderColor:"#eee"
        }, "fast") 
      });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jQuery Color Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) doesn't support just `borderColor`. You need to supply all four sides:

```
$('#tabbed a').hover(function() { 
    $(this).animate({ 
      backgroundColor: "#FBFBFB", 
      color:"#FD7A24",
      borderLeftColor:  "#000",
      borderTopColor:   "#000",
      borderRightColor: "#000",
      borderBottomColor:"#000"
    }, "fast") 
  }, function() { 
    $(this).animate({ 
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      color:"#65B1D3",
      borderLeftColor:  "#eee",
      borderTopColor:   "#eee",
      borderRightColor: "#eee",
      borderBottomColor:"#eee"
    }, "fast") 
  });
```

You can see from [line `10` of the source](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.color.js.txt) which properties it can animate:

```
...['backgroundColor', 'borderBottomColor', 'borderLeftColor', 'borderRightColor', 'borderTopColor', 'color', 'outlineColor']...
```